# Use strict mode for Swagger validation

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am using swagger-tools and Swagger Spec 2.0 to validate requests body in my Node JS service.
The issue is that JSON with additional properties passes validation and it affect internal logic of the service.
Example of valid JSON:

```
{
  "name": "proper object",
  "requiredProperty": "some value"
}
```

Example of still valid JSON that I want to block:

```
{
  "name": "proper object",
  "requiredProperty": "some value",
  "additionalProperty": "should not be here!!!"
}
```

Is it possible to use strict mode that will fail requests that contains additional properties?

Comment: https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools/issues/181